# filter active record results in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im completely new to Ruby on Rails. Im working on an existing API and I have a sql query which is executed with:

```
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(query)
```

The output of the results is:

```
{"availability"=>"In Stock", "available_to_purchase"=>1}
{"availability"=>"Void", "available_to_purchase"=>0}
{"availability"=>"Out of Stock", "available_to_purchase"=>0}
{"availability"=>"In Stores Only", "available_to_purchase"=>0}
```

I know want to get all values for availability based on `available_to_purchase` being 0. I have tried:

```
res = results.where(available_to_purchase: 0)
```

But I get an error saying:

```
undefined method `where'
```

I also tried:

```
res = results.select { |result| result.available_to_purchase == 0 }
```

But i end up with the error:

```
undefined method `available_to_purchase'
```

I know I can loop through and check available_to_purchase is 0, then add to a new array. But is there any method to quickly filter active record results based on value of a column?

Comment: Can the post `query` which you are using here `results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(query)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going directly through the `connection` avoids nearly everything `ActiveRecord` is intended to provide you. First thing, read [Active Record Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html). The Rails guides are really well put together and should contain everything you need for your first few weeks using the framework.

The reason you aren't getting the `where` method you expected is that it's a method on `ActiveRecord::Relation`, and `select_all` just returns you a list of hashes. By the time you call `results.where`, it's too late. You need to instantiate a `Product` model (or whatever would match your table name), which is as simple as:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Rails will look at the `products` table (again, I'm making up your table name) for the attributes a `Product` has, and then you'll be able to query based on them with `where`:

```
results = Product.where(available_to_purchase: 0)
```

The model will also have the accessor methods you were trying for, so you can do things like `results[0].available_to_purchase == 0` or `results[0].availability = 'Already in your house'`.

Answer (score 3):

In order to call .where on the results, you need an instance of an active record relation. Regular ActiveRecord queries will return this. select_all, however, returns an array of hashes. Array does not have the method where.

```
res = results.select { |result| result.available_to_purchase == 0 }
```

Your second error is because you are attempting to access ruby hash keys incorrectly. Properties must be accessed as`result['available_to_purchase']`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer to your question. I do agree with others though that you should be using `ActiveRecord`.

```
results.select { |result| result['available_to_purchase'] == 0 }
```